# Remove bar chart column names in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, charts

How can I remove the BarDataSet name from the chart as highlighted at the left bottom in the following image?

[image]

It's the text that I'm passing while creating BarDataSet object

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "ABC");
```

Comment: i think this is mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

Comment: Ohh yeah, it worked! but the x-axis values are cropped from bottom. can you help me with that

Comment: padding problem maybe it's hard without anycode